# How much is a sleeve of celery?

Tags: vegetables, language, measurements, celery

I was reading a recipe for [Slow Cooker Rosemary Garlic Beef Stew](http://www.budgetbytes.com/2014/10/slow-cooker-rosemary-garlic-beef-stew-slow-cooker/) and noticed that one of the ingredients called for a "sleeve" of celery. I've heard of a stalk of celery, but I've never heard of a sleeve. Here is the list of ingredients:

Ingredients

- ½ lb. (4 medium) carrots $0.55
- **½ sleeve celery $0.65**
- 1 medium onion $0.36
- 2 lbs. red potatoes $1.00
- 2 Tbsp olive oil $0.32
- 4 cloves garlic, minced $0.32
- 1½ lbs. beef stew meat $9.06
- Salt and pepper $0.05
- ¼ cup all-purpose flour $0.04
- 2 cups beef broth $0.30
- 2 Tbsp Dijon mustard $0.24
- 1 Tbsp Worcestershire sauce $0.06
- 1 Tbsp soy sauce $0.10
- ½ Tbsp brown sugar $0.02
- ½ Tbsp dried rosemary $0.15
- ½ tsp thyme $0.05

How much celery do I need to add to the recipe?

Comment: Perhaps they're referring to the bag that a whole celery heart comes in? Half a celery heart (about 6-8 stalks?) seems to be on par with the volume of 4 medium carrots.

Comment: I think you're right @Erica. "Sleeve" seems to be a common word for that style of celery packaging. Though the actual amount of celery in such a pack can vary, so it's not a great measurement for a recipe. Convenient, though, and forgiving in something like a stew. I'd say go ahead and make that an answer.

Comment: I agree it sounds like the package, but that's a very high celery to beef ratio! I'd add 2-3 stalks myself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This question is actually answered in a [comment to the recipe](http://www.budgetbytes.com/2014/10/slow-cooker-rosemary-garlic-beef-stew-slow-cooker/#comment-325472) you linked:

> kimberly says:
>
> Sorry for silly question, but the ingredient list says ” ½ sleeve
>   celery $0.65 “. do you mean 1/2 of a stalk or 1/2 of a bunch of
>   celery? [...]
>
> Beth M says:
>
> Yes, I meant a half bunch. Sorry about the confusion! :) I used about 4 stalks or so.
>   They cook down quite a bit.

Also there's a picture of the ingredients used:

[image]

So 4-5 stalks appears to be intended amount of celery. A recipe like this though is going to pretty flexible so if that seems like too much or too little it shouldn't be a problem if you go outside that range.

Answer (score 6):

My best guess is that the recipe is referring to the bag ("sleeve") that a whole celery heart comes in.

Half a celery heart (about 6-8 stalks?) seems to be on par with the volume of 4 medium carrots.

[Here's a Save-A-Lot grocery store listing for "sleeve celery"](http://save-a-lot.com/products/sleeve-celery), and the picture is of a celery heart.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at the same recipe and googled "what is a sleeve of celery?" and found your question.  Then I realized that on the version I'm looking at, when I scrolled down, the author had shown pictures of the ingredients.  4 carrots, 1 onion, and..... 5 CELERY STALKS.  So, that's what I'm going with.  I also like the answer of eye-balling it according to how much celery you want in proportion to the beef and carrots.  I don't like celery that well, but I'm going to use 5 stalks and hope it comes out okay.

Comment: The top answer here says exactly that - it even includes the picture.